# Customized layout and labels for multiple plots (GGPLOT2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, layout, customization

I have created a list of plots using the below code:

```
plots <- list()
for(i in 1:(k*k)){
  plots[[i]] <- ggplot(subset(mean_conf, Names == Names[i]), aes(x=nob)) + 
    geom_line (aes(y = Mean), color = "black") + 
    geom_line (aes(y = Left_Interval), color="black", linetype="twodash") +
    geom_line (aes(y = Right_Interval), color="black", linetype="twodash") + 
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank()) + expand_limits(y = 0)
}
```

using grid.arrange function (`do.call(grid.arrange,plots)`) brings below picture

[image]

I want to add text to specific areas on my plot. Something like this:
[image]

I have checked different functions, but I could not find a solution to my problem. 
I would appreciate any advice, suggestions, and help.

Comment: Have you try to facet your plot ? So, can you provide a reproducible example of your data in order people can try some solution on their own r  session ? (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you looked the cowplots package? this link may provide some clues: https://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/

Comment: Like dc37 says, try to omit the `subset()` statement in your main ggplot call, and add `+ facet_wrap(~ Names, ncol = 2)`

Comment: @dc37 Thanks for the recommendation, it was great. I had to create another column to match the length of my observations, and after that, everything worked just fine.

Comment: @teunbrand thanks it worked just great.

Comment: @peter thanks, I tried to use cowplots but I could not get it to work for my problem.

Comment: also check for the `patchwork` package, very simple of use.
https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork

Answer (score 0):

gridExtra and grid may be your friends for the layout you are after.

Here's a starter for 10.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)


p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, wt)) + geom_line()

ver <- textGrob("Plots verion 1", gp = gpar(fontsize = 15))
A_top <- textGrob("A", gp = gpar(fontsize = 15))
A_left <- textGrob("A", gp = gpar(fontsize = 15), x = unit(45, "mm"), y = unit(15, "mm") )

B_top <- textGrob("B", gp = gpar(fontsize = 15))
B_left <- textGrob("B", gp = gpar(fontsize = 15), x = unit(45, "mm"), y = unit(15, "mm"))

grid.arrange(ver, A_top, B_top, A_left, p, p, B_left, p, p, 
                  top = textGrob("Title", gp=gpar(fontsize = 20), x = unit(125, "mm")),
                  bottom = textGrob("Subtitle", gp=gpar(fontsize = 10), x = unit(65, "mm")), 
                  ncol = 3, 
                  widths = unit(c(50, 75, 75), "mm"), 
                  heights = unit(c(10, 75, 75), "mm"))
```

This gives you:

[image]

The following links can be explored for refining the layout

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html#title-andor-annotations

Comment: thanks it looks promising, I am going to check it out.

Comment: @ShazAl Hi did you have a chance to give the gridExtra approach a go?